sudo hangs after installing rtw89 modules
Today I installed rtw89 modules as instructed on this GitHub site. 
After that, top shows 100% CPU usage for ksoftirqd/1, and every time I try to use sudo, it just hangs, as described in this issue. 
Because of this, I can not even do sudo make uninstall
or unload what seems like problematic kernel modules
(rtw89core and rtw_8852ae, I guess?).  Rebooting doesn't help,
because as soon as I log in, I cannot use sudo. 
I tried blacklisting those two modules from GRUB, but without success –
not sure if those are really the right module names after all.

Maybe boot a live disk and mount the disk, wander through the module directory ( /lib/modules/$version/ ) and verify the module name, and while you are there, use modinfo directly on the module file and see if there are kernel command line options that might fix the driver rather than blocking it entirely.  That could lead to a permanent fix.

Thanks. I ended up booting a live disk and editing some files in /lib/modules/$version/ so that I was then able to boot into my system. However, I have forgot to write it here and up to this time I have already forgot, which files I changed. For that reason, I am not writing this as an answer.
